# Any recommendations for Tridion Multivariate or A/B testing?

Tags: 2011

We are researching the possibility of implementing an A/B testing tool for SDL Tridion 2011, and would appreciate any suggestions of preferred plugins available, or specific implementation patterns that have worked well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your implementation model, there is the cheap way to do it - formerly google website optimizer (now called [Content Experiments in Google Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1745147?hl=en)) or using Adobe's A/B variant testing product called [Target](http://www.adobe.com/marketing-cloud/testing-targeting/ab-testing.html).

I have also implemented Adobe's Dynamic Tag Manager on a Tridion 2011 instance and it worked great! Extremely easy!

Comment: SDL tries to play nicely with other systems as a good corporate player.

Answer (score 3):

Based on requirements and if you are on Tridion 2013 SP1, you might want to consider "Experiments" released as part of [SDL SmartTarget 2014 SP1](https://sdltridionworld.com/releases/release_news/smarttarget-2014-sp1.aspx). It is pretty cool and would address your requirements.

There was an [Multi Variate testing](https://sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/multi_variate_testing.aspx) extension that was available for 5.3 and 2009. You can extend it and try it out in 2011.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to sign-up for our trial here and check if [this integration](http://www.convert.com/integrations/sdl-tridion-ab-testing-multivariate-testing/) works for you.

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if you were to give some details of how the integration is done.

Answer (score 0):

There could be two custom variations that you can try for multivariate / AB testing:

1. Classify your content with the keywords and use the keywords to filter your content at the rendering time and show only the relevant content.
2. Other approach is to define content tags (geography, department etc.) in metadata which can be used for filtering the content and show only the relevant content.

I would recommend approach 2, as category classification requires those categories to be added as separate field in the content schema which becomes tedious when you have many categories.